# Group $G = S\times T$, a subgroup $H\le G$ satisfying $SH = G = TH$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Complete question is:

Let $S,T$ be two groups, $G = S\times T$. $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, satisfying $$SH = G = TH$$

(in which $S$ means $(S,e)$ and $T$ means $(e,T)$. Same notation as below.)

Try to prove:

(1) $S\cap H\lhd G , T\cap H\lhd G$

(2) If $S\cap H = \{e\} = T\cap H$, then $S\cong T$

(3) If $S\cap H = \{e\} = T\cap H$, $H\lhd G$, then $G$ is abelian group.

How far I have gone?

From the condition $SH = G = TH$, I know that the first part of $H$ must 'contain' $S$, and the second part must 'contain' $T$, and $H$ need to be a group. So $S\cap H\lhd G \iff S\cap H\lhd S$ (so as $T\cap H$), but I can't figure out why. As for (2), I plan to construct a bijection like 'diagonal' from $S$ to $T$. And I haven't thought about (3).

If you have any idea, please write down. Thank you!

Comment: What does $SH$ mean? $S$ and $H$ don't have compatible multiplication. Are you using $S$ here to mean the elements of $G$ where the second component is the identity from $T$?

Comment: @KevinP.Barry Yes, $S$ and $T$ means differently in different place. In $SH$, $S = (S,e)$. I'll edit this. :)

Answer (score 1):

This never got an answer, so here goes:

1. We need only do one case by symmetry. If $g\in G$, then $g=ht$ for some $h\in H$, $t\in T$. Notice that $(S\cap H)^h=S\cap H$ since $S$ is normal, so
   $$ (S\cap H)^g=(S\cap H)^{ht}=(S\cap H)^t.$$
   But $T$ centralizes $S$, hence centralizes $S\cap H$. This proves the result.
2. If $S\cap H$ is trivial and $SH=G$ then $G/S\cong=SH/S\cong H/(H\cap S)\cong H$. By symmetry $G/T\cong H$ and the result is shown.
3. Suppose, in addition, that $H$ is normal in $G$. If $H$ is non-abelian, let $h=(s,t)$ be an element of $H$, and $u\in S$. Since $H$ is normal in $G$, $h^u=(s^u,t)$ lies in $H$. But then
   $$ h^{-1}h^u=([s,u],1)\in H.$$
   Since $H\cap T=1$ we see that $[s,u]=1$, i.e., $S$ is abelian. Since $S\cong T$, $T$ is abelian.